# How to share data between two @ViewScoped beans?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to pass id (long) from one.xhtml to another .xhtml. 
Both the backing beans are `@ViewScoped` and I am trying to share long id between them.

I am getting error with `<f:viewParam/>`

> `com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException`: Unable to create
>   managed bean saleOrder.  The following problems were found:
>   - The scope of the object referenced by expression `#{param.foo}`, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (`saleOrder`) scope of view.

I am have following code.

```
@ManagedBean    
public class InvoiceView{
    private long number;
    // setter getter.
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public SearchInvoice{
    private List<InvoiceView> views;
    private InvoiceView selectedView;  // this is coming from <p:dataTable>
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SaleOrder {

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.foo}")
    private String number;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       //sysout number;
    }
}
```

I have following code in `searchInvoice.xhtml` file.

```
    <!-- I have not desclared <f:metadata/> -->
<h:commandButton value="Place Sale Order"
                 action="#{searchInvoice.forwardToSaleOrder}" <!-- this return saleOrder.xhtml string -->
                 rendered="#{not empty searchInvoice.views}">
        <f:viewParam name="foo" value="#{searchInvoice.selectedView.number}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: `#{param}` on `@ManagedProperty` requires a request scoped JSF managed bean which is in your case is a view scoped bean. If you still want to stick to a view scoped JSF managed bean with `@ManagedProperty` then, you may take another helper request scoped JSF managed bean and inject this view scoped JSF managed bean `SaleOrder` into that helper request scoped JSF managed bean and set the parameter value to the view scoped bean therein or use `<f:viewParam>`. See for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137638/1391249) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889226/1391249) respectively.

Comment: I changed scope of SaleOrder to '@RequestScoped', exception is removed but getting null for number.

Comment: I completely overlooked that you were using `<f:viewParam>` embedding inside `<h:commandButton>`. `<f:viewParam>` is meant for query-string parameters, if you were to happen to pass any. You cannot use it in a way you are showing in the question. In this case, you could better pass that value to the bean using a parameterized action(Listener) method (EL 2.2 or higher) or using `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{searchInvoice.selectedView.number}" target="#{saleOrder.number}"/>`. Replace `<f:viewParam>`. (No `@ManagedProperty` is needed - just a getter and a setter for number).

Comment: No need to change the bean scope. You could stick at the view scope as it was.

Comment: I tried this as well but it did not work. I am doubtful that, does <f:setPropertyActionListener> make 'number' available inside @PostConstruct init().

Comment: You want to set that property (`number`), **only when** you click that button (`<h:commandButton>`). Don't you? If it is that then, why do you even need to access that property in the method decorated by `@PostConstruct`? Why don't you simply move that logic associated with the `number` property to the `action` or `actionListener` method of that `<h:commandButton>`? Can't you do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<f:viewParam>` (JSF 2) in saleOrder.xhtml, which works with view scoped beans.
Check out [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters).

Comment: thank for reply. I removed @ManagedProperty and use <f:metadata> as described in doc but it return null for 'number'.

Comment: If it is null in your PostConstruct anotated method this is correct. You need to use <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{...}" />, it will be setted before call of this method.

Comment: I tried with <f:event> same as doc but it did not work. Still value is null.

Comment: Is f:metaData placed to the saleOrder.xhtml (not to searchInvoice.xhtml )?

Comment: Is there any logic in searchInvoice.forwardToSaleOrder method? If it just returns "saleOrder.xhtml" string, can you try to replace this command button with h:link to saleOrder view (with nested f:param), and try it with <f:metadata> in saleOrder.xhtml?